# OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint is deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have some filter that return 401 when some header is exist in the request.

my Filter is:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class BlockHeaderFilter implements Filter {

   private static final AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();

   @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       ...
       if (headerExist) {
          Exception failed = new Exception("Unauthorized request. x-private header is forbidden");
          authenticationEntryPoint.commence(
             httpServletRequest,
             httpServletResponse,
             new InsufficientAuthenticationException(failed.getMessage(), failed)
          );
       }
       ...
    }

}
```

This is working fine, but since Spring 5, seems that OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint is deprecated.

> 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint' is deprecated

```
/**
 * If authentication fails and the caller has asked for a specific content type response, this entry point can send one,
 * along with a standard 401 status. Add to the Spring Security configuration as an {@link AuthenticationEntryPoint} in
 * the usual way.
 *
 * <p>
 * @deprecated See the <a href="https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide">OAuth 2.0 Migration Guide</a> for Spring Security 5.
 *
 * @author Dave Syer
 * 
 */
@Deprecated
public class OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint extends AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler implements
        AuthenticationEntryPoint {
   ...
}
```

Looking at the migration guide (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) or anywhere else, I can't find the modern pattern for the same task.

Does anyone knows what was replacing OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint?

Thanks!

Comment: what you are looking for is probably `BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint.html

Comment: @Toerktumlare Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`AuthenticationEntryPoint` is a spring interface.

And if you look in the [api](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html) you can see under the **all known implementing classes** you can find the implementation [`BearerTokenAuthenticationEndpoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint.html)

`Baerer token` is more neutral then writing `oauth2` since there are other authentication standards that also use tokens.